# Firestore Kotlin Android Colleaction.add() exception

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Kotlin for programming. When I add document using the

```
collectionRef
                .add(settlement) // Adds Auto-ID
                .addOnSuccessListener({ documentReference ->
                    Log.d("Add Doc", "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.id)
                })
                .addOnFailureListener({ e ->
                    Log.w("Add Doc Failed", "Error adding document", e)
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener({ task ->
                    if (task.getException() != null) {
                        Log.w("Add Doc Failed", "Error adding document", task.getException())
                    }
                    if (task.isComplete()) { //try task.isSuccessful() if this is what you are looking for
                        Log.w("Add Doc Failed", "Error adding document")
                    }
                })
```

It always throws the exception, which addOnFailureListener not catch at all:

```
05-06 14:14:18.091 28113-28126/com.plabs.settle E/StorageHelpers: Failed to turn object into JSON
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.zzbf()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzi(Unknown Source:116)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzg(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:92)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzm.zza(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaw.zzaa(Unknown Source:27)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zzal(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdb.zzb(Unknown Source:41)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzci.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:139)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
05-06 14:14:18.101 28113-28126/com.plabs.settle W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzv: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.zzbf()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzi(Unknown Source:140)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzg(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:92)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzm.zza(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaw.zzaa(Unknown Source:27)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zzal(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdb.zzb(Unknown Source:41)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzci.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:139)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.zzbf()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzi(Unknown Source:116)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzg(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:92) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzm.zza(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaw.zzaa(Unknown Source:27) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zzal(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zza(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdb.zzb(Unknown Source:41) 
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzci.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:139) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
```

What I am doing wrong, where if i call collectionRef.get() i got all the records added so far, but none shown over the Firestore console.

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `settlement` object contains a Firebase user object, which can't be serialized to JSON by the Firestore client.

The Firebase SDKs can only handle serialization/deserialization of simple JSON objects, so you'll have to handle the user class in your own code.

Comment: settlement object just has user auth id in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem it's not in your code. I've been getting the same error after upgrading Firebase to 15.0.2.

Downgraded to 15.0.0 and it's working again.

Comment: Similar to widemos, I got this after upgrading to Firebase-Firestore 16.0.0. Downgrading back to 15.0.0 cleared this error

Comment: Funny thing though, It only crashed in Release builds, where debuggable was set to false.